# How do I make a If else statement with this code in compilejava.net?

Tags: java

In my computer programming class we have to answer the following:
Consider the following game. Alice writes down two integers between 0 and 100 on two cards. Bob gets to select one of the two cards and see its value. After looking at the value, Bob commits to one of the two cards. If he chooses a card with the largest value, he wins; otherwise he loses. Devise a strategy (and corresponding computer program) for Bob so that he guarantees to win strictly more than half the time.

And I made this program to try and solve the problem:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.println("First Number: " + r.nextInt(100));
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + r.nextInt(100));
  }
}
```

What I need to know is how can I (or if I need to) make a if/else statement that chooses the randomly generated number over at least 50 and says choose this number over the other.

Comment: First thing to do is to save the generated values in variables so that you can compare them. If you generate when you print, you can no longer access the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need two variables where you can store the generated random numbers.

```
int number1 = r.nextInt(100);
int number2 = r.nextInt(100);
```

After that you can compare the variables with an if-statement:

```
if(number1 < number2)
 System.out.println(number1 + " is smaller!");
else
 System.out.println(number1 + " is bigger!");
```

I'm very sure that you can modified this little example to compare your values with 50 or whatever you want? Good luck with learning programming. You can find a good Java tutorials on the [Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store both of the numbers in integer variables instead of printing them

```
int first = r.nextInt(100);
int second = r.nextInt(100);
```

Then create a variable that stores Bob's selection

```
int selectedCard;
```

Making Bob always check the first card makes things easier.

```
if(first > 50)
    selectedCard = 1;
else
    selectedCard = 2;
```

Then you can print out if Bob wins or loses

```
if(selectedCard == 1) {
    if(first > second)
        System.out.println("Bob wins!");
    else
        System.out.println("Bob loses!");
}
else {
    if(second > first)
        System.out.println("Bob wins!");
    else
        System.out.println("Bob loses!");
```